# Interstitial ads on iOS don't show a close button

Tags: ios, admob, adsense

A few months ago, we added Google's interstitial ads to our iOS app and there was a widespread issue of there not being a close button for some of the ads. This resulted in many angry emails, as users were forced to quit the app and hope to get a different advertisement the second time around that they could actually close. It even resulted in a few 1-star reviews. This forced us to remove the ads from the app completely. We obviously prefer to keep them, but are wondering if the issue has since been addressed/if there is anything we can do to proactively ensure this does not occur again? Has anyone else experienced this issue? Were you able to fix it? If so, how?